# The existence of concatenation functions in Godel Numbering?

Tags: logic, computer-science, incompleteness

I know that there are many schema of Gödel Numbering, and each has its own method of Concatenation, n★m. 
But is there a general proof that shows 'For every Gödel Numbering scheme there exists a Concatenation Function'?

Comment: The concatenation of $n$ and $m$ is just $n\cdot 10^k + m$, where $k$ is the number of digits in $n$.

Comment: @MJD that won't work this way you cannot distinguish nm from n★m.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is more the other way around without contentation no Godel numbering.

Godelnumbering is just a translation from formulas and proofs to numbers and from the Godelnumbers back to the same  formulas and proofs.

I think in principle any translation system that can do this can be used as godelnumbering system.

Be aware:

- The numbering system  also needs to be able to translate proofs to numbers and back
- all translations need to be lossless and exact
- it must all be done in the axioms of arithmetic.

So it is not only translating a formula to an number , it is much more

Hope this helps